# scaled Schoenfeld residuals slope of regression line

Tags: cox-model, schoenfeld-residuals

If a regression line of scaled Schoenfeld residuals versus time (or log time) has a non-zero slope, proportionality is violated. However, what can we tell from the slope of the regression line? If it is positive, does this mean that the effect of a covariate becomes more important over time? If it is negative, does the effect get less important over time? What if it crosses 0?

Answer (score 1):

*If it is positive, does this mean that the effect of a covariate becomes more important over time?*

It means the value of the regression coefficient increases over time. The effect doesn't necessarily become "more important", because if it is negative in the beginning, then increasing the coefficient will bring the effect closer to 0.

*If it is negative, does the effect get less important over time?*

Same answer as above.

*What if it crosses 0?*

Then the coefficient changes sign, indicating the effect changes from positive to negative (or vice versa) over time.